# Can't find starting point of android application

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

So, I'm practicing some reverse engineering and now I chose an Android Trojan in order to inspect (Marcher overlay Android trojan from Contagio Mobile malware samples). I've decompiled it using the [Apktool](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool) and It generated the smali files and everything. The problem is I can't locate the starting point of the application. In the manifest it says:

```
...
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.paranbijuv.aijuy.bkqbjl.huitou" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
... <!-- no other main/launcher in the xml, only these -->
```

But there is no "**com.paranbijuv.aijuy.bkqbjl.huitou**" inside the decompiled sources. Actually there is no "**paranbijuv**" package at all. To make sure Apktool didn't generate wrong sources I've run a `strings` command directly into the `classes.dex` file and also no reference to these classes. My question is how can I reach to the starting point of the app in this case?

**Edit**: Or, if it is the case of some obfuscation, then the app would have to have a entry point anyway... what sort of obfuscation could cause the entrypoint class to be missing from the classes.dex, if possible?

Comment: Questions about reverse engineering should be asked at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: the question is about `code`. I need to find the starting part of the code. Where the execution begins. So it fits for SO

Comment: Suit yourself. You may have a better chance of getting an answer on the re.SE site, however. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Search that name in `public.xml` file and then find it's `id` and search that in the project.